# JMeter JMS subscriber how to read a BytesMessage from the topic

Tags: jmeter, activemq-classic

In my Jmeter scenario  have to receive a BytesMessage from a JMS tpoic in ActiveMQ and alter it a bit and push back to another topic ans a BytesMessage.

I was using JMS subscriber and Publisher for this.

Using JMS Subscriber I was able to receve the message from the topic, but could not find a way to read it so that I can work on  it to alter.

My sampler looks like follows.

[image]

When I run this I can receive the message  from the topic.

[image] [image]  [image]

This says that there is a ByteMessage of 212 bytes, how can I capture this message , and use it to build my next request ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture **full** response of the sampler into a JMeter Variable go for the next steps:

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of your request
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `response`
   - Regular expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     Explanation:

     > `()` = grouping
     >
     > `(?s)` = single line modifier
     >
     > `^` = line start
     >
     > `.` = wild-card character
     >
     > `*` = repetition
3. That's it, now you will have the **whole** response saved into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), you will be able to refer it as `${response}` or [`${__V(response)}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) where required

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)